# Sony WH-1000XMX2 bluetooth headset fails to properly connect autoamtically

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

Sorry for a noobish question, but I have a problem with my headset and I've been searching for an answer for a while now - to no avail.

When my headset gets automatically connected to my laptop (for example when I turn on my headset and the laptop have been already running) The sound is set to "mono".
When I restart the whole bluetooth service - the same thing happens.

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

When I disconnect my headset and connect it again manually (in the GUI)- it works fine with stereo and with high fidelity set by default.

I tried following [that](https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6) and maybe output from this command may help you.
When it's badly connected:

```
journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-01-29 03:11:02 NZDT. --
Apr 01 12:00:55 Yeti-Book gsd-media-keys[3341]: Unable to get default sink
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book rtkit-daemon[1367]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book rtkit-daemon[1367]: Successfully made thread 14688 of process 3178 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book rtkit-daemon[1367]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
Apr 01 12:01:08 Yeti-Book gsd-media-keys[3341]: Unable to get default source
Apr 01 12:01:09 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Apr 01 12:01:25 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Apr 01 12:01:41 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
Apr 01 12:01:57 Yeti-Book kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

When it's properly connected:

```
journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-01-29 03:11:02 NZDT. --
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel:  kthread+0x121/0x140
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel:  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel:  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel:  ? SyS_exit+0x17/0x20
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel: Code: 00 00 00 75 26 48 8b 7b 08 e8 1a eb a2 ff 48 8b bb 08 92 00 00 48 89 83 70 a9 00 00 be 08 00 00 00 e8 22 5a 08 00 31 c0 5b 5d c3 <0f> 0b eb d6 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel: ---[ end trace 34e0ddc48eba8d61 ]---
Apr 01 13:10:43 Yeti-Book kernel: amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GPU pci config reset
Apr 01 13:10:44 Yeti-Book gnome-shell[3153]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: activate: Error: Error invoking IBus.set_global_engine_async: Expected function for callback argument callback, got undefined
                                             setEngine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:207:9
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                             activateInputSource@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:490:13
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                             _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27
                                             activate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:65:9
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                             _inputSourcesChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:620:13
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                             reload@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:369:9
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                             _ibusSetContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:691:9
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                             _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27
                                             _setContentType@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:183:9
                                             wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
```

I'm searching for full a problem solution (problems stops existing) or a fast enough workaround (how to disconnect and connect a device again using the command line).

the laptop is HP Elitebook 850 G3
system: Ubuntu 18.04

```
radoslaw@Yeti-Book:/ $ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic


radoslaw@Yeti-Book:/ $ uname -a
Linux Yeti-Book 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cheers!

---

**edit:** `dmesg` output with a bad connection connected

```
[516028.247434] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[516028.257416] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[516028.257436] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
```

after reconnecting two more lines appeared:

```
[516028.247412] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[516028.247434] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[516028.257416] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[516028.257436] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[516111.185452] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[516120.375748] input: 70:26:05:89:03:B8 as /devices/virtual/input/input45
```

Comment: You may simply be SOL. Despite what fanboys will tell you, linux still has a lot of problems with any hardware that isn't very, very mainstream (and sometimes even then). Frankly it looks to me like it may be simply yet another half-assed driver module. The output of `dmesg` might be illuminating though, especially right after the headset connects incorrectly.

Comment: hey. thank you for your response - I added dmesg output to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as a workaround you can use the following:

1. install `bluetoothctl`
2. `sudo bluetoothctl`
3. this should result in something like that:

```
# paired-devices 
Device CB:B2:CG:26:FD:80 <DEVICE_1_NAME>
Device 70:26:03:89:03:B8 <DEVICE_2_NAME>
```

4. copy the string between "device" and the device name (for example 70:26:03:89:03:B8)
5. paste it into the following script

```bsh
sudo bluetoothctl << ANSWERS
disconnect 70:26:03:89:03:B8
ANSWERS

sleep 5s

sudo bluetoothctl << ANSWERS
connect 70:26:03:89:03:B8
ANSWERS
```

and your device should be reconnected.
the sleep in the middle is for the driver to finish disconnecting (otherwise you'll get errors)

hope that helps :)

cheers

Comment: I'd still love to find a permanent solution, but this is a great workaround. thank you!